# HtmlWebpackPlugin injects relative path files which breaks when loading non-root website paths

Tags: javascript, express, webpack, react-router

I am using webpack and the HtmlWebpackPlugin to inject bundled js and css into an html template file.

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
   template: 'client/index.tpl.html',
   inject: 'body',
   filename: 'index.html'
}),
```

And it produces the following html file.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    ...
    <link href="main-295c5189923694ec44ac.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="main-295c5189923694ec44ac.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This works fine when visiting the root of the app `localhost:3000/`, but fails when I try to visit the app from another URL, for example, `localhost:3000/items/1` because the bundled files are not injected with an absolute path. When the html file is loaded, it will look for the js file inside the non-exist `/items` directory because react-router hasn't loaded yet.

How can I get HtmlWebpackPlugin to inject the files with an absolute path, so express will look for them at the root of my `/dist` directory and not at `/dist/items/main-...min.js`? Or maybe I can change my express server to work around the issue?

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../dist'));

app.get('*', function response(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'));
});
```

Essentially, I just need to get the line:

```
<script src="main...js"></script>
```

to have a slash at the start of the source.

```
<script src="/main...js></script>
```

Answer (score 258, accepted):

Try setting the publicPath in your webpack config:

```
output.publicPath = '/'
```

HtmlWebpackPlugin use the publicPath to prepend the urls of the injects.

Another option is to set the base href in the `<head>` of your html template, to specify the base url of all relative urls in your document.

```
<base href="http://localhost:3000/">
```

Comment: Thank you, adding `output.publicPath = '/'` was the solution.

Comment: This will not work if you're running behind reverse proxy.

Comment: You could also use simply `<base href="/">` to avoid having to hardcode the host name in the HTML template, or having to interpolate variables.

Comment: I had to set publicPath = '' and add <base href="~/dist/"> since my site is a ASP.Net MVC project using IIS and a virtual directory.

Comment: Lead me in the right direction.  Setting `publicPath` to `""` (an empty string) worked to fix my problem.

Answer (score 22):

In fact, I had to put :

```
output.publicPath: './';
```

in order to have it working in a non-ROOT path.
At the same time I was injecting :

```
   baseUrl: './'
```

into

```
<base href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.metadata.baseUrl %>">
```

With both parameter set, it worked like a charm.

Comment: This shows the `URL` on browser as `https://localhost/myproject/%3C%=%20htmlWebpackPlugin.options.baseUrl%20%%3E#/project/1`. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Where are you setting `baseUrl: '.'` is it in the HtmlWebpackPlugin options? `{ meta: { baseUrl: './' } }`?

Comment: @SomethingOn I don't have this webpack project on hand right now, and I think a lot of things have changed since I posted this answer (including default value). So yes, this is certainly where it should be set, but `'./'` is the correct value.

Comment: Now It can inject base tag directly. [inject base tag](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#base-tag)

Comment: Dumb but really effective 2nd approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

in webpack config

```
config.output.publicPath = ''
```

in your index.html

```
<base href="/someurl/" />
```

this should do it.