# What is the right way to set a different <base> for dev/staging/production

Tags: webpack

```
<base href="">
```

for dev and production are different(for production it's subfolder). What is the good way to build different base with webpack?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

the best what I found so far was to put this property in config(HtmlWebpackPlugin option):

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  ...
  baseUrl: process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development'?'/':'/app/'
})
```

and then output it in index.html:

```
<base href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.baseUrl %>" />
```

Comment: For some reason <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.baseUrl %> never gets parsed to the given baseUrl anymore.

Comment: Version 2.x of the HtmlWebpackPlugin changed how templates are handled, so the old substitutions no longer work. See https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/docs/template-option.md

Comment: I use `npm install --save-dev base-href-webpack-plugin`. [Here is how to!](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base-href-webpack-plugin)

Comment: for some reasons I have to add `minify: { removeAttributeQuotes: false }` or update baseUrl like soe `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? '"/"' : '"/app/"'`, otherwise output will be <base href=/app/ />, but not <base href="/app/" />

Answer (score 5):

If you have a `template` option set to an HTML file then Version 2.x of the plug-in will not perform any substitution.

In this case, you will need to modify @stever's answer as follows:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  ...
  template: './src/index.ejs',
  baseUrl: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'?'/':'/app/'
})
```

and rename your `index.html` file to `index.ejs`

Answer (score 4):

Now it is easy to do it.

Install the base-href-webpack-plugin in your project:

```
npm install --save-dev base-href-webpack-plugin
```

and import this code in webpack file:

```
// Import package
const { BaseHrefWebpackPlugin } = require('base-href-webpack-plugin'); // Or `import 'base-href-webpack-plugin';` if using typescript

// Add to plugins
plugins: [
  new BaseHrefWebpackPlugin({ baseHref: '/' })
]
```

Reference: https://github.com/dzonatan/base-href-webpack-plugin

Comment: For webpack v3 use ^1.0.0. For webpack v4 use ^2.0.0. Did you observe this?

Comment: Yes, I was using 1.0.2 if I remember well. Also, I use the template option in HtmlWebpackPlugin, maybe it's related.

Comment: It throws TypeError: Cannot read property 'compilation' of undefined

Answer (score 4):

In **Webpack 4** I have tried the baseUrl in **[HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin)** , but it's never gets parsed in the html. So you need a new plugin called **[BaseHrefWebpackPlugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base-href-webpack-plugin)** along with HtmlWebpackPlugin

**Webpack.config**

```
 new HtmlWebpackPlugin(), //this will create default template
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'MyApp' //replace title
  
        }),
        new BaseHrefWebpackPlugin({
            baseHref: process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development' ? '/' : '/MyApp/'
        })
```

**Html**

```
    <base href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.baseUrl %>">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
```

Answer (score 3):

For `Webpack 5`, `html-webpack-plugin` **natively** supports setting the `base` tag in the document, by using `base` option (`base-href-webpack-plugin` is no longer necessary):

https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#base-tag

The `base` option can be:

- *string*

```js
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  'base': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? '/' : '/MyApp/'
})
```

- *object*

```js
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  'base': { 
    'href': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? '/' : '/MyApp/'
  }
})
```

The above configs are identical and will both inject the `base` tag in HTML:

```html
<base href="...">
```

- *boolean(false)*

```js
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  'base': false
})
```

By default, the option is set to `false` and base tag will not be injected.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Angular CLI 6, you can specify `baseHref` and deploy url as part of your production config (projects > xxx > architect > build > configurations > production) inside `angular.json`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webpack, you will certainly have to set `output.publicPath` to the same value.
See [HtmlWebpackPlugin injects relative path files which breaks when loading non-root website paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34620628/htmlwebpackplugin-injects-relative-path-files-which-breaks-when-loading-non-root/40906811#40906811)