# Switching base tag between dev and prod

Tags: html, tags, radix

```
<!-- local -->
<base href="/appname/src/main/webapp/" >
<!-- deployed -->
<!--<base href="/appname/">-->
```

Currently, I need to manually comment/uncomment these tags whenever I want to check in my code or deploy it, and then switch it back when I'm developing.

What can I do so I don't have to keep changing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the right way to set a different <base> for dev/staging/production](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35204924/what-is-the-right-way-to-set-a-different-base-for-dev-staging-production)

Comment: Is this answer useful? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35204924/what-is-the-right-way-to-set-a-different-base-for-dev-staging-production](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35204924/what-is-the-right-way-to-set-a-different-base-for-dev-staging-production)