# Angular 2 Webpack Starter File Loading / Path Problems When Hosting Project

Tags: angular, hosting, github-pages

I'm working on an angular 2 TypeScript project built off of [Angular 2 Webpack Starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter). I am having trouble hosting the site live. It's working great when I use npm run server and check localhost:3000

[image]

---

and also it works great when I run npm run server:prod and check localhost:8080

[image]

Nice!

I then go to host the site through the Github gh-pages branch. My project is named "SafeFoods" and gh-pages adds an extra SafeFoods into the path here in the address bar. The problem with this is that I have files looking to be loaded at a path that doesn't have SafeFoods (but is otherwise identical).

[image: Doesn't work when hosted live]

I have tried changing "baseUrl" in the webpack.common.js file, but this breaks the site when I run the dev server and prod server!

Does anyone know how I can make it so that the site works in all three situations?
thanks.

live hosted site: https://jimtheman.github.io/SafeFoods/
original repo: https://github.com/JimTheMan/SafeFoods

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35204924/what-is-the-right-way-to-set-a-different-base-for-dev-staging-production

Comment: @yurzui thanks for trying, but this link is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I see your [`index.html`](https://github.com/JimTheMan/SafeFoods/blob/master/ng-s/dist/index.html) only include url with an absolute path

```
 /assets/icon/apple-icon-57x57.png
```

You should use relative paths only: `assets/icon/apple-icon-57x57.png`

See "[GitHub pages and relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16325664/6309)"

> In an HTML document at `http://www.foo.com/bar/doc.html`, the link to `assets/css/common.css` will **get resolved by appending it to the prefix of the URL of the HTML document without the last part of the path** (without doc.html), i.e. the link will resolve to `http://www.foo.com/bar/assets/css/common.css`, not to `http://www.foo.com/assets/css/common.css` as you claim.

Of course, [using Jekyll would be easier](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/332#issuecomment-18952908):

> In `_config.yml`, set the `baseurl` option to `/project-name` -- note the leading slash and the absence of a trailing slash.
>
> Now you'll need to change the way you do links in your templates and posts, in the following two ways:
>
> When referencing JS or CSS files, do it like this: `{{ site.baseurl }}/path/to/css.css` -- note the slash immediately following the variable (just before "path").
>
> When doing permalinks or internal links, do it like this: `{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}` -- note that there is no slash between the two variables.

Comment: That is how my project builds. How can I change it to output relative paths instead of absolute?

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using Jekyll?

Comment: @Jimothy From your project `AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/`, you can try a `css-to-string-loader` for webpack: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/730#issuecomment-229682254

Comment: My issue is not that css is not being loaded. Please check my question.