# Prefixing Angular2 routes in different environments

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Let's say in development you're developing an Angular2 application that runs on `localhost:3000`. All your routes work fine.

But you want to deploy to `myserver.com/myapp/` so that your routes in production will now be prefixed with `myapp/`. Now your routes all break because Angular2 parses its own routes on the frontend.

Is there a convenient way to prefix all your Angular2 routes in one environment but not another?

Comment: Did you try `<base href="myapp/">`?

Comment: Why isn't your development environment reflecting (in some part) what production has?  If production is using a prefix, why isn't your development app using that prefix?

Comment: Thanks! `base href` worked. For posterity, this is how to set it in Webpack: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35269814/2242700

Comment: @Makoto Just isn't how our business wants to set up dev right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following line in your package.json file in the "scripts" section.

`"build_prod": "ng build --prod --extract-css=false --base-href=/myapp/",`

Then when you build your artifacts for production, run `npm run build_prod` in your terminal.

Upload the content of the dist to your server. It will work.