# Setting base href using Environment variables

Tags: reactjs, deployment, create-react-app, react-router-v4

Need to set the href value for `<base href=""/>` tag based on build environment configuration.

Eg:

Staging should have `<base href="/staging" />`

Prod should have `<base href="/" />`

**Current setup:**

Build command:

```
"build": "sh -ac '. .env.${REACT_APP_ENV}; react-scripts build'",

"build:staging": "REACT_APP_ENV=staging npm run build",

"build:prod": "REACT_APP_ENV=production npm run build",
```

.env.staging.js:

```
REACT_APP_BASE_HREF=/staging
```

index.html:

```
....

<base href="" + process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL />

....
```

This doesn't seem to work in index.html. While similar setup works for JS files

(Probably because JS files are parsed and bundled into a single file and the bundler reads the values at that point of time)

Things tried:

index.html:

`<base href=process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL />`

`<base href="process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL" />`

`<base href="%process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL%" />` (similar to PUBLIC_URL variable)

Setting basename property along with Browser Router also does not solve the problem

Comment: Take a look at webpack.DefinePlugin: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30061249/1300562

Comment: Thanks, but did not solve the problem. The process variable is being parsed in JS, but NOT in index.html

Comment: I would go with https://stackoverflow.com/a/35269814/5346095

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem was solved. Follow these steps:

1. In package.json Set `homepage` key to `""`
2. In .env.staging file Set `PUBLIC_URL=/survey`
3. No need to use `<base href>`. Can be removed from HTML file
4. Change links for stylesheet to

   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

No need to add process.env

Comment: Looking back at this answer, this is right for dev env only. because: on proper ci, you build once, and deploy to multiple servers... once you set the public_url, it uses it on build only

Comment: Public url is a c-name i suppose, so even with multiple-server deployments, it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: where to fine .env.staging  file

Comment: @Faisal this file can be created at the project root level if it does not exist.

Comment: You should not consider removing the base href a good answer at all. This is wrong. Please follow the HTML standards and HTTP standard properly!

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```html
    <base href="%PUBLIC_URL%/"> <!-- Note the slash at the end -->
```

- `PUBLIC_URL` is a env variable accessible through `process.env`.
- You can set `PUBLIC_URL` env variable on your terminal `export PUBLIC_URL=/subdir`, or your `.env` (check create-react-app on it, it use dotenv under the hood).
- You can also set `homepage` in `package.json` to  `/subdir`, it will also work.
- `PUBLIC_URL`, if not set, is taking homepage value.

---

**If you only need to prefix link inside index.html, then you do not need a base tag.**
The base tag is useful for image link for example, that are inside your components:

If you serve your app in `domain.com/` you can do:

```html
<img src="/assets/duck.jpg" />
```

Instead, if you serve your app in `domain.com/subdir/`, you can do:

```html
<img src="/subdir/assets/duck.jpg" />
```

or if you have set the base tag like above:

```html
<img src="assets/duck.jpg" /> <!-- Base tag only work with relative paths, same as ./assets/duck.jpg -->
```

Note that the above: `src="assets/duck.jpg"` will also work on your **front page** (`/subdir`) **without** base tag ! The path of the image is relative to the path you are currently on. This mean, that on `/subdir/some-route`, the web browser will be search at `/subdir/some-route/assets/duck.jpg` on the server, without a base tag. With a base tag, you can navigate to any route, and each image src path will ignore the path you are currently on, and start from the base tag href prop value.

---

In case you have `background-image` in **scss (sass) files**, I recommend moving it to html, like that:

```
<section style={{backgroundImage: `url('assets/background-form.jpg')`}}>
 ...
```

Sass for me, was not compiling with the relative path above. Also, you can try making a relative path to the assets folder `../../public/assets/background-form.jpg`, but it will fail due to special restriction `ModuleScopePlugin` that forbid you to link relative path outside of `src` folder (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory/44115058#44115058)).

Comment: I only need to add prefix in URL wherever %PUBLIC_URL% used, I don't want to add env. PUBLIC_URL or add homepage property in package.json. how can I do that? if I am create env variable it is creating build under one more subfolder. Can you please help me here. Thanks