# How should I configure create-react-app to serve app from subdirectory?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, single-page-application, create-react-app

I have classic web application rendered on server. I want to create admin panel as single page application in React. I want to server admin panel from https://smyapp.example.com/admin/. I try to use `create-react-app` but it assumes that i serve SPA from root URL. How should I configure `create-react-app` to serve app from `"admin"` subdirectory? In documentation I found `"homepage"` property but if I properly understand it requires complete url. I can't give complete url because my app is deployed in few environments.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "I can't give complete url because my app is deployed in few environments"?

Comment: @GabrielBleu In docs I found something like "homepage": "http://mywebsite.com/subdirectory", but I don't want to give full domain name here.

Comment: As routing can be handled by `router` `basename`, I think this url is only for bundles, maybe you can link to a shared one like `statics.mywebsites.com` ?

Answer (score 84):

In addition to your **requirements**, I am adding mine:

- It should be done by CD, through an env variable.
- If I need to rename the subdirectory, I should only have to change the env variable.
- It should work with react-router.
- It should work with scss (sass) and html.
- Everything should work normally in dev mode (npm start).

I also had to implement it in Angular2+ project not long ago, I found it harder to implement in React then in Angular2+ where you are good to go with `ng build --base-href /<project_name>/`. [source](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#deploy-to-github-pages)

---

#### Short version

1. Before building, set `PUBLIC_URL` env variable to the value of your subdirectory, let use `/subdir` for example. You can also put this variable into your `.env.production` ([in case you do not have that file you can check the doc](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables))
2. In `public/index.html` add the base element bellow, this is for static files like images.

```html
<base href="%PUBLIC_URL%/">
```

3. Also in `public/index.html`, if you have custom `link` element, make sure they are prefixed with `%PUBLIC_URL%` (like `manifest.json` and `favicon.ico` href).
4. If you use `BrowserRouter`, you can add `basename` prop:

```html
<BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL} />
```

5. If you use `Router` instead, because you need access to `history.push` method, to programmatically change page, do the following:

```
// history.tsx
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory({ basename: process.env.PUBLIC_URL });
```

```html
<!-- Where your router is, for me, App.tsx -->
<Router history={history}>
  ...
</Router>
```

6. Use relative links inside your elements

```html
<!-- "./assets/quotes.png" is also ok, but "/assets/quotes.png" is not -->
<img src="assets/quotes.png" alt="" />
```

7. Move your `background-image` links from scss to jsx/tsx files (note that you may not need to do that if you use css files):

```scss
/*remove that*/
background-image: url('/assets/background-form.jpg');
```

```html
<section style={{backgroundImage: `url('assets/background-form.jpg')`}}>
...
```

**You should be done.**

---

#### Additional informations

I preferred to use `PUBLIC_URL` instead of `homepage` in `package.json` because I want to use env variable set on gitlab to set the subdir. Relevant resources about the subject:

- https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths
- https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/
- https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/998

`PUBLIC_URL` override `homepage`, and `PUBLIC_URL` also take the domain name, if you provide one. If you set only `homepage`, `PUBLIC_URL` will be set to the value of `homepage`.

---

If you do not want to use a base element in your index.html (I would not know why), you will need to append `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` to every link yourself. Note that if you have react-router with a base element, but have not set `basename` prop, you will get a warning.

---

Sass won't compile with an incorrect relative path. It also won't compile with correct relative path to your `../public/assets` folder, because of `ModuleScopePlugin` restrictions, you can avoid the restriction by moving your image inside the src folder, I haven't tried that.

---

There seem to be no way of testing relative path in development mode (npm start). [see comment](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/527#issuecomment-393158807)

---

Finally, theses Stack Overflow links have related issues:

- [Can I set a base route in react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38196448/can-i-set-a-base-route-in-react-router/58506212)
- [Setting base href using Environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45208595/setting-base-href-using-environment-variables/58506035)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Using the environment variable is much better than package.json

Comment: This worked fine for me in dev but not in production. I have a weird setup though where I can't serve from / which might have been messing with the static/asset files.

Comment: Using .env files was actually a great piece of advice for running the app both in dev and production environments without any pain

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but I don't really think this is a "short" version!

Answer (score 52):

For create-react-app v2 and react-router v4, I used the following combo to serve a production (staging, uat, etc) app under "/app":

package.json:

```
"homepage": "/app"
```

Then in the app entry point:

```
 <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
  {/* other components */}
 </BrowserRouter>
```

And everything "just works" across both local-dev and deployed environments. HTH!

Comment: What about DRY (Do not repeat yourself)? In this case you have your public url in two places..

Comment: I needed `<base href="/app/" />` in public/index.html as well to make the assets work - and assets use relative urls (like `<link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" />`).

Answer (score 32):

You should add entry in `package.json` for this.

Add a key "homepage": "your-subfolder/"  in your **package.json**
All static files will be loaded from "your-subfolder"

If there is no subfolder and you need to load from same folder you need to add the path as "./" or remove the entire line which has `"homepage": "xxxxxxxxxx"`

`"homepage": "./"`

**From the official docs**

By default, Create React App produces a build assuming your app is hosted at the server root.
To override this, specify the homepage in your package.json, for example:

> "homepage": "http://mywebsite.com/relativepath",

**Note:** If you are using `react-router@^4`, you can route `<Link>`s using the basename prop on any `<Router>`.

From [here](https://kiranvj.blogspot.com/2018/08/create-react-app-custom-build-to.html) and also check the [official CRA docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths)

Comment: Spent an entire day to deploy a CRA build, finally figured out the solution - thanks to this answer!

Answer (score 11):

To get relative URLs you can build the app like this:

```
PUBLIC_URL="." npm run build
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use `react-router` and its *relative* `basename` parameter which allows you to serve your app from a subdirectory.

`basename` is the base URL for all locations. If your app is served from a sub-directory on your server, you’ll want to set this to the sub-directory. A properly formatted basename should have a leading slash, but no trailing slash.

For instance:

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/calendar"/>
```

So `<Link to="/today"/>` will render `<a href="/calendar/today">`

See: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string

Answer (score 2):

put in package.json something like this:

**"homepage" : "http://localhost:3000/subfolder",**

and work fine on any public or local server.  Of course, subfolder must be your folder.

Comment: will images and other assets from create-react-app also be served from that folder?

Comment: this does not happen for me, I am stuck trying to get the assets from sub directory

Answer (score 1):

In our case, we did everything as described in [Ambroise's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58508562/12084678), but got a blank page in production with no errors or warnings in the console. It turned out to be a problem with BrowserRouter - we got it working by setting BrowserRouter's basename like so:

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/our_subfolder/" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar kind of  issue. Need to serve **react app from Godaddy hosting**. let's say for example the context path should be **/web** ie:- http://example_123.com/web
Following changes works fine for me with React 18.2.0 , react-router-dom: 6.11.0

1. set homepage in package.json to /web ie: homepage: "/web"
2. update basename in BrowserRouter to process.env.PUBLIC_URL

```
    <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}> 
      {/*Your components*/} 
    </BrowserRouter>
```

3. build app and put your build inside /web folder in public_html ie: /public_html/web
4. on godaddy inside public_html created index.html and redirect that to /web

```
<html> <head>

<title>welcome to example_123</title> 

<!--<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.2; URL=web/index.html"> -->
<meta name="keywords" content="automatic redirection"> 

</head> 

<body> </body> 

</html>
```

**Bonus**

If want to put your content inside /web and don;t want context path. follow below steps :-

1. set homepage to /web in package.json
2. put your build inside /web in public_html
3. just move index.html from /web to publi_html ie.: put index.html generated by build inside public_html and all other files in /web

Answer (score -2):

You can specify the public path in your webpack configuration  along with use of react route basepath.

Link to Public Path: https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/

Note that public path will be both leading and trailing slashes / to be valid.