# How to change base url in create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs

How to change base url in create-react-app? So that the application does not open with *localhost:3000/*, but ***localhost:3000/myurl***?

Comment: are you using react-router in your project?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I configure create-react-app to serve app from subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49429906/how-should-i-configure-create-react-app-to-serve-app-from-subdirectory)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a lot of adjusting if you want react to launch in a subdir. like changing path of assets, components etc. [This Guide is a good starting point](https://skryvets.com/blog/2018/09/20/an-elegant-solution-of-deploying-react-app-into-a-subdirectory/)
on how to accomplish your needs. Again Its not recommended, if you want like to switch to /myUrl as soons as it launches, you could do a `componentDidMount()` and force it there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using react-router, you can achieve that by using a `Redirect` to navigate your app from `/` to `/myurl`.

First, declare a route config like this:

```
// routers.js
import React from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export const redirectRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    exact: true,
    // handle redirect case: / -> /myurl/
    render: () => <Redirect to={`/myurl`} />
  }
]
```

Then, inside your `App.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { redirectRoutes } from "./routers.js";


// generate app reidrect routes
const redirectRouteComponents = redirectRoutes.map(route => (
  <Route
    key={route.path}
    path={route.path}
    exact={route.exact}
    render={route.render}
  />
));

const App = () => <Router>{redirectRouteComponents}</Router>;
```