# Node.js react serves incorrect asset url

Tags: node.js, reactjs, path, reach-router

I have been experiencing node issues for resolving my path for my Create React App.

**Issue:**

> Assets (chunk.js) files are resolving to relative path rather than
>   absolute path.

When I visit the website from root folder (example.com) and hit the `/games/` URL it's working fine. However, if I refresh, it's appending `/games` into the URL.

For example:

```
http://movies-finder.surge.sh/movies/419704
```

**^ Visit the page and refresh the page.**

**Correct Link:**

> https://example.com/static/js/main.b9f8ee12.chunk.js

**Incorrect Link:**  (This is happening when user Refreshes the page)

> https://example.com/games/static/js/main.e50e1c49.chunk.js

I just want to make sure, I don't encounter `/games` when my assets are being accessed.

(There is no need for `/games/`) hence broken :(

**Folder Structure:**

```
-/
 - server.js
 - public
    - index.html
 - package.json
 - Build
```

**Package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "games-finder",
  "version": "0.1.2",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": ".",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001/",
  "dependencies": {
    // dependencies
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    // dev dependencies for the project.
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "server": "node-env-run server.js --exec nodemon | pino-colada",
    "dev": "run-p server start",
    "heroku-dev": "run-p server start"
  }
}
```

**server.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const path = require('path');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(pino);

app.get('/api/greeting', (req, res) => {
  const name = req.query.name || 'World';
  res.send(JSON.stringify({ greeting: `Hello ${name}!` }));
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {

  // Serve any static files
  app.use(express.static('build'));

  // Handle React routing, return all requests to React app
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Please help me identify the issue. I've spent like couple days trying to debug the issue.

I just want to make sure, I don't encounter `/games` when my assets are being accessed.

Comment: Please share a github repo. It's too hard to narrow down the issue without a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because of `"homepage": "."` in your package.json, try to remove this line.

Detailed description here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58508562/9173730