# Issues deploying react under custom root path "/app" with create-react-app and react-router

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm deploying an app on a host that has the following setup:

- https://example.com/app1
- https://example.com/app2
- etc.

I need to deploy under a custom root path `/app` for my React app that will sit under this umbrella. I'm using `react-router v5` and `create-react-app`.

## Problem

When I build the app (I'm using [vercel's serve](https://github.com/vercel/serve)), I get a blank page. When I go to `localhost:5000/app/`, nothing shows up.

I did all the suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43011207/using-homepage-in-package-json-without-messing-up-paths-for-localhost) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49429906/how-should-i-configure-create-react-app-to-serve-app-from-subdirectory), but still can't get my app to load.

I'm also confused: what's the difference between using react-router's `basename` and CRA's `homepage` field? Should I be using both, or one or the other?

EDIT: Potentially found the problem. Setting `homepage=/app` also changes the paths for my JS bundle, which it wasn't recognizing (hence the blank page). I manually added a `app` folder inside my `build` dir, like so: `build/app/static` and it worked. Shouldn't CRA do this automatically?

## My setup

#### app.tsx

```
<Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
  ...
</Router>
```

#### package.json

```
scripts: {
  "build-prod": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT=production react-app-rewired build",
},
...
"homepage": "/app",
```

#### Command to serve the prod build locally

```
> npm run build-prod && serve -s build -l tcp://0.0.0.0:5000

The project was built assuming it is hosted at /app/.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.

Find out more about deployment here:

  bit.ly/CRA-deploy
```

I navigate to `http://0.0.0.0:5000/app/` and get a blank page (no network calls).

## What I tried

- set `homepage: "/app"` in `package.json` [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43011207/using-homepage-in-package-json-without-messing-up-paths-for-localhost)
- set the basename for react-router [source](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string)
- The [CRA docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths) shows an example using the full path of the website. That didn't work either:

```
"homepage": "https://example.com/app",
```

Comment: Is the `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` value coming in correctly? I could not find it in the build command, or if you have included it in a .env file. Essentially, `homepage` is used to access your assets relative to the value provided, e.g. your CSS files and images. Whereas the `basename` value is used by react-router to handle client-side routing relative to the value provided. Both should be included to make the app run correctly.

Comment: Yes, when I console.log `process.env.PUBLIC_URL`, I am seeing `/app`. Ah, I see - thanks for the clarification on `homepage/basename`!. So I see part of the problem - adding `homepage=/app` also changes the JS bundle's path from `static/js/main.js` to `app/static/js/main.js`. I manually added an `app` folder inside my `build` dir and moved my `static` folder inside it. It worked. Shouldn't this happen automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working, although it's a workaround.

As Mohit's comment mentions, the `homepage` field makes it so all the assets are pre-pended by that sub-path defined in `homepage`. I was getting a blank screen because it couldn't find the new path to my JS bundle, aka it went from serving `/build/static/js/..` to `/build/app/static/js/..`.

### Solution (workaround)

- Create a new folder called `app` (or whatever your new root path is called) under your `build` directory.
- Move your `/build/static` folder to `build/app/static`.
- This is what it looks like with `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN pwd
RUN echo $(ls -1 $pwd)
RUN echo $(ls -1 ./build)
RUN mkdir -p ./build/app
RUN mv ./build/static ./build/app # now it should be /build/app/static
RUN echo $(ls -1 ./build)
```

You can take out the `pwd` and `echo` lines, I added it so I could see it working.

I don't know why CRA doesn't do this by default. It might be because I'm using `react-app-rewired`, which messes around with CRA's webpack config?

Comment: I'm also having this problem but I've not seen anyone else comment on it so there must be some reason it's not happening for anyone else. did you ever get to the bottom of it?

Comment: OK I get it now (in my case at least). if you are wanting to serve it from an external web server, you will be copying the whole `build` folder into the `/app` folder on the web server, so the index file will be `/app/index.html` and static already will be `/app/static`, which means you shouldn't need this workaround. In my case I was wanting to serve it with npm's `serve -s build` which does require a workaround - it seems there's no way for `serve` to use a folder other than root

Comment: Also ran into the same issue. Thanks for providing a clear solution/workaround.