# React adding "build" to end of base url

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm creating a basic React app using `create-react-app`.
When I cd into the root folder and run `npm run start` or `yarn start`, the project url is `http://localhost:3000/build`.

Why is it adding `build` to the end of the url and how can I make the server load  `http://localhost:3000/` instead?

Comment: Can you show us your package.json file and other config files ?

Comment: You have been fiddling with the config files, haven't you ;) CRA specification clearly states that "start" script runs at localhost 3k. You have either fiddled with PUBLIC_URL environment variable at either OS level or process.env.PUBLIC_URL at NodeJS level or switched its environment from "development" where it should be for this script

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I configure create-react-app to serve app from subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49429906/how-should-i-configure-create-react-app-to-serve-app-from-subdirectory)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the *package.json* in your project folder root (the one that spawned into existence after you created the app using the `create-react-app`) there are `scripts` defined.

There you can see what gets executed when you run `npm run start` or `yarn start` -> the `"react-scripts start"`

BTW, you can just `npm start` - no need to `npm run start`.

So where are these react scripts and what gets called?

Well, in the project root folder is your `node_modules`. And in it there is a `react-scripts` subfolder and in it a folder named `scripts` and in it a file named `start.js`. This is what actually gets run.

This chunk

```
const urls = prepareUrls(
      protocol,
      HOST,
      port,
      paths.publicUrlOrPath.slice(0, -1)
    );
```

Determines URLs and it basically, "glues togather"/concats those parts the one you are interested in is:

```
paths.publicUrlOrPath.slice(0, -1)
```

the paths object is defined in:
`node_modules\react-scripts\config\paths.js`

In this file, this piece of code determines what you are after:

```
const publicUrlOrPath = getPublicUrlOrPath(
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
  require(resolveApp('package.json')).homepage,
  process.env.PUBLIC_URL
);
```

So you have fiddled with `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` either in Node or maybe at OS level? I am not sysadmin. Bottom line is, you changed this one way or the other.

I can give you a "get out of jail for free" card:

In the root folder there is a `package.json file` and in it, you can add this line:

```
"homepage": "",
```

This will force the `require(resolveApp('package.json')).homepage,` to come into play, and use that instead as the final part of your URL.

Comment: Amazing, this is super helpful! Thanks so much :)