# How to change base url of create react app?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-router-dom

I'm using [react-router-dom](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) with create-react-app.

Running scripts with `yarn start`, it starts with `http://localhost:3000/(myprojectname)`,
not `http://localhost:3000/`

When routing with react-router-dom, I have to remove `myprojectname` from url and then add page routes.

There seems to be a problem with the initial setting of the project,

how can I start from `http://localhost:3000/` ??

---

Add package.json, router code.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "cau-burger-online-order-system",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.2",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.16",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "brace-expansion": "^2.0.1",
    "gh-pages": "^3.2.3",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "homepage": "https://myprojectname"
}
```

App.tsx:

```
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import './App.css'

import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

import Detail from 'pages/detail/Detail'
import GlobalStyle from './GlobalStyle'
import Home from 'pages/home/Home'
import Login from 'pages/login'
import Signup from 'pages/signup'

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <div className="App">
        <div className="auth-wrapper">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
            <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/detail" component={Detail} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` file? You may just need to edit the `homepage` entry. Alternatively, if you plan on deploying the app into a nested directory on your server then you can specify a `basename` prop on the router.

Comment: can you add your router code here?

Comment: Change `homepage` to `"./"` and try it again locally.

Comment: @DrewReese Changing like this `<Route exact path="./" component={Login} />` doesn't show any difference.

Comment: Nono, in your `package.json` file, the `homepage` entry, update it to `"./"`... leave your route paths in your app as they are.

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks for your help!! `homepage` was  the problem!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I configure create-react-app to serve app from subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49429906/how-should-i-configure-create-react-app-to-serve-app-from-subdirectory)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your `package.json` file change the `homepage` entry to a relative path, excluding any sub-domain/nested directory.

```
{
  "name": "cau-burger-online-order-system",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    ....
  },
  "scripts": {
    ...
  },
  ...,
  "homepage": "https://hy57in.github.io/2021-Industry-Hands-On-Project"
}
```

to

```
{
  "name": "cau-burger-online-order-system",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    ...
  },
  ...,
  "homepage": "./"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You just need to do two things for changing base Url for ReactRouterDom  dom.
It is useful when you host the website on website like github page and or at url something like Https://website.com/mywebsite or at sub link .

First -  You have to add a attribute Like -

`<BrowserRouter basename='/mywebsite'>`

Or open your package.json and add Before building your project for production

```
"homepage": "/your-subdirectory",
```

for my case :

```
"homepage": "/mywebsite",
```

I hope this will help, Feel free to ask if you stuck in this .

Answer (score 1):

I found some helpful information on https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect
"Rendering a  will navigate to a new location. The new site will override the current location in the history stack like server-side redirects (HTTP 3xx) do."

Is there any way you can share your repository? I'll be the best way to help you. Pretty much, I need a little bit more information to help you.