# How to host multiple Create-React-App production builds with NGINX, each in a separate directory (without Docker)

Tags: reactjs, nginx, create-react-app

I'm trying to find a way how to host multiple (currently 2) React applications, each created with [CRA](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html). Both apps should run behind a single instance of NGINX and be accessible in a separate directory:

app1 -> `http://localhost/app1`

app2 -> `http://localhost/app2`

The 2 React applications where created like this:

```sh
npx create-react-app app1
npx create-react-app app2
```

To host both React applications using NGINX, the production build of each CRA app (`npm run build`) is copied to NGINX static directory `/var/www/app[1|2]`

```sh
# App1
npm run build
cp build/* /var/www/app1

# App2
npm run build
cp build/* /var/www/app2
```

This is how NGINX can be setup to host a single CRA app:

```
# /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        root /var/www/app1;
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to extend this example so both CRA apps are hosted by one NGINX.

Which modifications are necessary, both to NGINX `site.conf` and each React application itself?

I pushed a code showing my (incomplete) example above to Github for reference: https://github.com/wolkenarchitekt/multiple-cra-apps-behind-nginx.
The code is using docker-compose for simplicity, but in the end the whole stack should run without Docker, so running separate Docker services for each React app is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to run both React apps on the same domain but different subfolders, you should just need two `location` blocks:

```
root /var/www;
location /app1/ {
        index index.html;
    }
location /app2/ {
        index index.html;
    }
```

The necessary changes in the React apps usually include:

- changing the `homepage` field in the `package.json` [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52363490/3083470)
- (only applies if react-router is used, older versions should work similarly) change the `basename` for `BrowserRouter`to your subdirectory: `<BrowserRouter basename='/app1'>`

**EDIT:**

After checking out your repo (before you pushed the new branch) I just got it working with the following Dockerfile (way worse for development since every code change requires a rebuild, I just like multistage builds and this would be more suited for a production environment):

```
FROM node:16 as builder1
WORKDIR /var/app
COPY app1/package.json .
COPY app1/package-lock.json .
RUN npm i
COPY app1/public/ ./public
COPY app1/src/ ./src
RUN npm run build

FROM node:16 as builder2
WORKDIR /var/app
COPY app2/package.json .
COPY app2/package-lock.json .
RUN npm i
COPY app2/public/ ./public
COPY app2/src/ ./src
RUN npm run build


FROM nginx:mainline-alpine
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./nginx/site.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=builder1 /var/app/build/ /var/www/app1
COPY --from=builder2 /var/app/build/ /var/www/app2
```

The following `site.conf` worked for me:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www;

    location /app1 {
        index index.html;
    }
    location /app2 {
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

I just had to change `homepage` to `/app1` and `/app2` respectively, change `app2/App.js` to actually output `App2`, and then

```
docker build . -t testreactmultiple:latest
docker run -it -p 3000:80 docker.io/library/testreactmultiple:latest
```

I hope this helps you reproduce the working container that errors when the index is requested but works fine when `/app1` or `/app2` is requested.

Comment: Thanks! However when configuring nginx the way above, it will search for each apps files inside `/var/www/app1/app1/...`: `2022/02/15 14:33:18 [error] 30#30: *2 "/var/www/app1/app1/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.21.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /app1/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8009"
`

Comment: Try `root /var/www`, since nginx apparently appends the location path (didn't know that)

Comment: Using `/var/www` as root won't work either. This time, the react app will try to load static resources outside its `homepage` using the root dir: `/static/...`: `2022/02/15 16:00:33 [error] 30#30: *1 open() "/etc/nginx/html/static/css/main.073c9b0a.css" failed`. Seems that `homepage` doesn't work as expected. I also tried various approaches of passing `PUBLIC_URL`. None of these worked.

Comment: I pushed the suggested changes to a branch my playground-repo: https://github.com/wolkenarchitekt/multiple-cra-apps-behind-nginx/tree/taxel
as I said this doesn't solve the problem yet

Comment: Is the react app making requests to `localhost:port/static/file.ext` instead of `localhost:port/app1/static/file.ext` or is `nginx` resolving it wrong? (can be figured out in devtools, network tab). This will at least narrow down the problem to be either a wrong `nginx` config (more likely, since I'm less familiar with that) or something with react not working.

Comment: @Wolkenarchitekt I got it working with Docker and updated my answer.

Comment: This. is. awesome! Works like a charm. Thank you so much, also for the nice multi-stage-dockerbuild (pretty useful for future react/nginx-debugging).