# Express, how to always serve static directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

So I need Express to always serve a static directory. These are a lot of guides on how to just serve index.html, for instance [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing). They use this code:

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

However the problem for me is that the '/*' route only serves index.html, not any files it pulls in, e.g main.js. I basically need my app to always serve 'build/' no matter which path the visitor is on, as the routing is handled by the frontend with React Router. So for instance:

```js
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

Does not work, because it removes the path. A user landing on '/aa/bb/cc' should be served the same content (express.static) as a user on '/'. I've tried `app.use('/*', express.static(...)`, however this results in `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'` in the browser because seemingly every request is routed to the static index.html file?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put it in an `app.get` do it on the main app.js file as `app.use` per the Express documentation: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43373134/11441482

To make all files use absolute paths (e.g src="/main.js") I had to set output.publicPath to '/' in my frontend Webpack configuration. This property is used by html-webpack-plugin. See this question for more details: [HtmlWebpackPlugin injects relative path files which breaks when loading non-root website paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34620628/htmlwebpackplugin-injects-relative-path-files-which-breaks-when-loading-non-root)