# webpack-dev-server seems to only work with static files

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I use *webpack* and *webpack-dev-server* to build and run the client side code in my web application.

But when I run *webpack-dev-server* without `writeToDisk` set to `true` then I am served an empty page: [example video.](https://youtu.be/YRO1Qejk4Hg)

To me it seems like webpack-dev-server can build and write the files to disk but fails to serve them from memory.

I would like to run webpack-dev-server with needing to set `writeToDisk` so any answer which can achieve this would be awesome.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with [my configuration for webpack dev server.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34620628/htmlwebpackplugin-injects-relative-path-files-which-breaks-when-loading-non-root)

The following configuration worked for me:

```js
devServer: {
  contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, '../laravel/public'),
  open: true,
  openPage: 'wwwroot/',
}
```